# Gnuplot: How to plot points with pm3d?

Tags: plot, 3d, gnuplot

I want to plot a data file with 16 given points using pm3d in gnuplot, but I also want all this given points to be shown on the plot. That's how my data file (xyz.dat) looks like:

```
# X     Y     Z
  0     0     0.632  
  0     5     0.46
  0     10    0.37
  0     50    0.41
  5     0     0.95
  5     5     0.66
  5     10    0.59
  5     50    0.5
  10    0     1.5
  10    5     0.96
  10    10    0.77
  10    50    0.5
  50    0     1.5
  50    5     1.5
  50    10    1.5
  50    50    0.98
```

Here is my code so far:

```
 set ticslevel 0  
 set dgrid3d 30,30  
 set palette defined (0 "blue", 0.75 "white", 1.4 "red")  
 set style lines 100 lt 5 lw 0.5  
 set pm3d hidden3d 100  
 set grid  
 set view 74,216  
 unset key  
 splot 'xyz.dat' using 1:2:3 with pm3d
```

This produces the following output:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOp6b.png)

I'm really glad with this result, but I want to make this 16 given points from the data file clearly visible on this plot, but I become just something like that:

[Outputs with points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAbak.png)

I want this 16 points (and only this 16 points) to be clearly shown on the "Output"-picture, but I don't know, how to change my code for that. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficulty you are encountering is not because of pm3d but rather because you have enabled auto-generation of gridded surfaces via the command `set dgrid3d`.  Any plot style that can become a surface is caught by this.  You can work around this by using a non-surface plot style like `with labels`.  Of course you don't have any actual label text, but you can still draw a point indicating the label position.  Your plot command becomes

```
splot 'xyz.dat' using 1:2:3 with pm3d, \
      'xyz.dat' using 1:2:3:("") with labels point pt 7
```

Comment: I use gnuplot for the first time, is there is an opportunity to become the plot like on the output-picture without dgrid3d? This labels doesn't fit all points exact, but this solution is better than anything that I have tried, thank you!

Comment: The point symbols from the labels show exactly where the original data points are.  If they do not lie on the gridded surface it is because the gridded surface is an interpolated fit.  You may try adjusting the fit using various options to the `set dgrid3d` command as described in the manual.